# In File I/O, how do I remove printing newline

Tags: python, labview

I'm reading multiple sensor's data from arduino through Serial monitor.
I wrote a python script for writing the data from serial monitor to a txt/csv file.
That file is later read by LabVIEW.
The problem is Serial monitor shows values like this:

```
1,42.00,444.00,2.17,-15.43,-49.25,79.12,26.18,-8218,-23404,18432,-579,-757,371,620.00
2,42.00,444.00,2.17,-15.27,-49.30,79.29,26.27,-8110,-23344,18384,-535,-782,396,235.00
3,42.00,443.00,2.17,-15.64,-49.33,79.29,26.27,-8274,-23276,18228,-615,-761,371,425.00
```

But this is how it shows up on txt file:

```
1,42.00,444.00,2.17,-15.43,-49.25,79.12,26.18,-8218,-23404,18432,-579,-757,371,620.00

2,42.00,444.00,2.17,-15.27,-49.30,79.29,26.27,-8110,-23344,18384,-535,-782,396,235.00

3,42.00,443.00,2.17,-15.64,-49.33,79.29,26.27,-8274,-23276,18228,-615,-761,371,425.00
```

And while reading on labVIEW, these extra line are read as value=0 by LabVIEW. Hence I'm getting an errored data and graph that surges to a value and goes back down to 0.

"So how do I **remove the extra newline while writing to a file.**"

I read somewhere that adding: newline=' ' will do the job.
But it's not happening.
Also I feel it's not just "\n" thats' getting printed, it's "\n\r" i Guess.

Code Snippet:

```
import serial
from datetime import datetime as dt
import time
serial_port='COM5'
baud_rate=9600
path="D:\LabVIEW\DB_Store.txt"
ser=serial.Serial(serial_port,baud_rate)
if ser.is_open:
    while ser.is_open:
        with open(path,'a') as f:
            print("Data flushed!")
            line=ser.readline()
            #f.write(str(dt.now()))
            f.write(str(line))
else:
    print("Port is closed!!!")
```

Comment: use re.sub('\n', '', input)

Comment: Perhaps you can simply read every line except the ladt character like `line = ser.readline()[:-1]`

Comment: Can you change the Arduino or LabVIEW code, or only the Python code you've posted? If you can't change the LabVIEW code I would propose removing the `[labview]` tag as the question isn't really about LabVIEW.

Comment: What is the Arduino code?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use `str.strip()`. This will remove any space/tab/newline characters from the start and end of your string.

If you wish to preserve spaces/tabs you can provide just newline as an argument eg

```
line.strip('\n')
```

To only strip off the left or right, you can use the `str.lstrip` and `str.rstrip` variants.

In your usecase I'd suggest a simple strip would suffice eg:

```
f.write(line.strip())
```